# Best way to integrate dynamic XML content for getting indexed in Google/Bing

Tags: xml, iframe, seo

I am looking for a good way to integrate dynamic content (job offers) from an XML feed to a website. The purpose is to have this content indexed on typical search engines (google, bing) so people looking for a specific job offering will be able to get redirected to my website through search.
I am creating the XML feed myself by using the API provided by successfactors, showing a job description and the corresponding deeplink to the application within the succesfactors backend.

back to the question - do you think it is possible working with iFrames to show the job offerings and still get indexed or would recommend another way?

(Of course - putting static content manually each day would work obvs - but I am looking for an automated solution)

Thanks for your help and ideas!!

Comment: Why not try something in Ruby? Get the data from SF using oData and create a whole different site.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes I would not host the content in an IFRAME - for example I could include a IFRAME that loads google.com, but would not expect to receive any SEO benefit from Google's site.

It is certainly still possible to automate this process to include the content on your site however, you would just need to implement a server side programming language (PHP, Java, etc) to parse the XML feed and include it on your site's HTML.

This is a tutorial on reading XML with PHP - http://fuelyourcoding.com/reading-xml-with-php/

Comment: Thanks doublesharp - I will look into that!

Comment: considering - I would not be allowed to use PHP on this webpage - I guess using JS to integrate the dynamic content would be even worse than using an iFrame regarding crawlability, right?

Comment: Not 100% sure on that - Google does render Javascript content, although I'm not sure how well it counts in their PageRank algorithms. It does at least have the advantage of being hosted locally instead of included from an external domain.